# python-Изменение xml файла docx / ошибка при сборке

Tags: python-3.x, xml, ms-word, docx, python-docx

В моем случае мне нужно дублировать <w:r> (в котором лежит <w:t> text </w:t>). Я распаковываю .docx и пытаюсь внести изменения в document.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<w:document xmlns:wpc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingCanvas" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:m="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:wp14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:wp="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:w10="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" xmlns:w14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordml" xmlns:wpg="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingGroup" xmlns:wpi="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingInk" xmlns:wne="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2006/wordml" xmlns:wps="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingShape" mc:Ignorable="w14 wp14">
<w:body>
        <w:p w:rsidR="005F670F" w:rsidRDefault="005F79F5">
            <w:r>
                <w:t>Test</w:t>
            </w:r>
            <w:bookmarkStart w:id="0" w:name="_GoBack"/>
            <w:bookmarkEnd w:id="0"/>
        </w:p>
        <w:sectPr w:rsidR="005F670F">
            <w:pgSz w:w="12240" w:h="15840"/>
            <w:pgMar w:top="1440" w:right="1440" w:bottom="1440" w:left="1440" 
                     w:header="720" w:footer="720" w:gutter="0"/>
            <w:cols w:space="720"/>
            <w:docGrid w:linePitch="360"/>
        </w:sectPr>
    </w:body>
</w:document>
```

мой код:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET
import copy
def inserting_file(source: str, search: str, insert: str)-> str:
    """ source: что парсим
        search: что будем заменять
        insert: вставка
    """
    temp = source.split(search)
    if len(temp) > 2:
        if not temp[1]:
            return  
    for i in [i for i in range(1, len(temp), 2)]:
        temp.insert(i, f"{search}\n{insert}")    
    return "".join(temp)
with open('./test/word/document.xml') as f:
    source = ''.join([i for i in f])
search = r"</w:r>"
write = """<w:r><w:t>Test</w:t></w:r>"""
print(inserting_file(source, search, write))
with open('./test/word/document.xml', 'w') as f:
    f.write(inserting_file(source, search, write))
```

при обратной сборке в docx и попытке открыть сформированный файл вылезает от ворда: Приложением Word в документе test.docx обнаружено содержимое, которое не удалось прочитать. Попробовать восстановить содержимое документа? Если вы доверяете источнику этого документа, нажмите кнопку "Да".
ну и при нажатии на да:
Ошибка Word при попытке открытия файла.
Попробуйте выполнить следующие действия.

- Проверьте разрешения на доступ к документу и диску.
- Проверьте, достаточно ли памяти и места на диске.
- Откройте файл с помощью конвертера резервных копий.
  (test.docx)

Что я делаю не так и почему не собирается нормально?
При добавлении <w:r> ручками у меня все открывается при сборке.
На всякий случай прикреплю архивации/разархивации:

```
import os, zipfile, shutil

def unpack(directory='test'):
    zipFile = zipfile.ZipFile(directory + '/test.docx', 'r')
    zipFile.extractall(directory)
    zipFile.close()
    os.remove(directory + '/test.docx')

def rec_dir(directory, files, zipFile):
    for i in files:
        if os.path.isdir(directory + i):
            zipFile.write(directory + i)
            rec_dir(directory + i + '/', os.listdir(directory + i), zipFile)
        else:
            zipFile.write(directory + i)
    return True

def pack(directory='test'):
    os.chdir(directory)
    files = os.listdir()
    zipFile = zipfile.ZipFile('test.docx', 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
    rec_dir('', files, zipFile)
    zipFile.close()

    for i in os.listdir():
        if i != 'test.docx': 
            if os.path.isdir(i): shutil.rmtree(i)
            else: os.remove(i)

pack()
#unpack()
```

Comment: А "вручную пробовали архив открывать, смотрели содержимое, всё ли там выглядит как планировалось, а в сравнении со старым файлом? Открыть архив и смотреть удобно в `Far`, например.

Comment: да, в том то и дело, что все выглядит так, как должно быть) голову поломал, почему такая проблема возникает.

Comment: А сравнить ещё с тем файлом, где "ручками" тег добавили? ) Тут только искать где же различия. Может метод архивации не тот, может файлы внутри архива чем-то отличаются. Может не основной файл отличается, а дополнительные. Тут только всё сверять.

Comment: сверил посимвольно. идентично все ( отличается только добавлением моей конструкции ). Сравнил еще саму архивацию. 0 зацепок.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я нашел решение моей проблемы (в приведенном ниже коде вставляю в дополнение слова из словаря):

```
def inserting_file(source: str, search: str)-> str:
    """ source: что парсим
        search: что будем заменять
        insert: вставка
    """
    def wrapper(text):
        rand = random.randint(0,15)-1
        write = f"""<w:r>
                    <w:t> {slovar[rand]} </w:t>
                </w:r>{search}"""
        return text + write
    temp = source.split(search)
    return "".join([wrapper(i) for i in temp[:-1]]) + temp[-1] 
unpackstart() #эту функцию я прикреплял к вопросу (только добавил в название папку)
with open('./start/word/document.xml') as f:
    source = ' '.join([i for i in f])
search = r"<w:r>"
with open('./start/word/document.xml', 'w') as f:
    f.write(inserting_file(source, search))
packstart()
```